# Analytic continuation of the Zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I have a question about the following continuation of the Zeta function:

Consider

$$ \intop_{0}^{\infty}e^{-nt}t^{z-1}dt=\frac{1}{n^{z}}\intop_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt=\frac{\varGamma\left(z\right)}{n^{z}} $$

So that $$ \varGamma\left(z\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{z}}=\intop_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-nt}\right)dt=\intop_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}\frac{1}{e^{t}-1}dt $$

And thus $$ \zeta\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{\varGamma\left(z\right)}\intop_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^{t}-1}dt $$

Or $$ \zeta\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{\varGamma\left(z\right)}\left[\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^{t}-1}dt+\intop_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^{t}-1}dt\right] $$

Now, the zeta function suppose to have singularity at $ z=1 $ (and that supposed to be the only singularity)

But I dont understand how can we see that $$ \intop_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^{t}-1}\begin{cases}
converge & z\neq1\\
diverge & z=1
\end{cases} $$

Seems like we'll always have a problem at $ t=0 $

I would really appreciate clarification here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\Re z>1$. Using the Maclaurin series of ${\frac{t}{{e^t  - 1}}}$ and integrating term-by-term, we find
$$
\frac{1}{{\Gamma (z)}}\int_0^1 {t^{z - 2} \frac{t}{{e^t  - 1}}dt}  = \frac{1}{{\Gamma (z)}}\frac{1}{{z - 1}} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{\Gamma (z + 1)}} + \frac{z}{{12\Gamma (z + 2)}} -  \cdots .
$$
Now the RHS can be extended analytically to the whole of $\mathbb C$ except $z=1$. The original integral, however, makes sense only for $\Re z>1$.

Comment: Sir can you explain why can we exchange the order of summation and integration here?

Comment: @euler0.0 Because the power series converges absolutely and uniformly on $\left[ {0,1} \right]$. Actually it converges absolutely and uniformly on any compact subset of the disc $|t|<2\pi$.